# using a macro to define the body of a tabular / & separator problem

Tags: tables, macros, recursion

I'd like to create a macro that can create and fill a multiline tabular with 4 entries per line from something like `\bidding{3H,4S,5C,X,XX,-}` where the number of entries is of course dynamic.

I have tried different ways but I cannot overcome the problem to get latex to interpret the `&` separator correctly.

I always end up with either the & being not interpreted at all or with the

```
Misplaced alignment tab character &.
```

error message. Trying to derive this from another solution found here that does the recursive part, the latest failure (ending up with the error message) looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kvsetkeys}
\usepackage{etexcmds}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\commut}[2]{{#1}&{#2}}
\newcommand*{\qcommut}[1]{%
  \let\commut@list\relax
  \comma@parse{#1}\@qcommut
  \typeout{\meaning\commut@list}% for debugging
  \expandafter\commut@list
}
\def\@qcommut#1{%
  \ifx\commut@list\relax
    \def\commut@list{#1}%
  \else
    \edef\commut@list{%
      \noexpand\commut{%
    \etex@unexpanded\expandafter{\commut@list}%
      }{#1}%
    }%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\qcommut{A,B,C,D,E}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This will not provide me with the groups of 4 a line, but I am just eager to get the `&`-problem solved, the rest should be easy... Any help appreciated.

Comment: One should assume that (in your example), you'll never call `\qcommut` with more elements than there is elements in your `tabular` column specification? That is, no checking is necessary in that regard.

Comment: Right. This is just to illustrate my problem. The issue I am unable to solve is that the & separator is not handled as intended. Probably I'll run into other issues later ;)

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why such much code is produced for this simple task. I mean that the following code is succesfull.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\tabline{}
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\qcommut#1{\qcommutA#1,,\tabline\cr}
\def\qcommutA#1,{%
   \if^#1^\else
      \ifx\tabline\empty \else\addto\tabline{&}\fi
      \addto\tabline{#1}\expandafter\qcommutA
   \fi
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \qcommut{A,B,C,D,E}   
    \qcommut{A,B}
    \qcommut{A,B,C}
  \end{tabular}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the programming environment is not necessarily the one you're used to, here's a way to do it in `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\qtabular}{ O{4} m }
 {
  \peter_qtabular:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__peter_qtabular_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l__peter_qtabular_input_seq
\int_new:N \l__peter_qtabular_cols_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \peter_qtabular:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__peter_qtabular_body_tl
  \int_zero:N \l__peter_qtabular_cols_int 
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__peter_qtabular_input_seq { , } { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__peter_qtabular_input_seq
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__peter_qtabular_body_tl { ##1 }
    \int_incr:N \l__peter_qtabular_cols_int
    \int_compare:nTF { \l__peter_qtabular_cols_int = #1 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__peter_qtabular_body_tl { \\ }
      \int_zero:N \l__peter_qtabular_cols_int 
     }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__peter_qtabular_body_tl { & }
     }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{*{#1}{c}}
  \tl_use:N \l__peter_qtabular_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\qtabular{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}

\qtabular[3]{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}
\end{document}
```

The body of the table is prepared in advance and then delivered in the `tabular` environment.

[image]

---

A small modification to also fill the last row (with empty cells) in order to be able to use `\hline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\qtabular}{ O{4} m }
 {
  \peter_qtabular:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__peter_qtabular_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l__peter_qtabular_input_seq
\int_new:N \l__peter_qtabular_cols_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \peter_qtabular:nn #1 #2
 {
  % clear the token list that will contain the body
  \tl_clear:N \l__peter_qtabular_body_tl
  % this counter tells us what column we're at
  \int_zero:N \l__peter_qtabular_cols_int 
  % split the input into items at commas
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__peter_qtabular_input_seq { , } { #2 }
  % do a mapping
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__peter_qtabular_input_seq
   {% add the current item to the body and increment the counter
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__peter_qtabular_body_tl { ##1 }
    \int_incr:N \l__peter_qtabular_cols_int
    % if the counter equals the number of columns, add \\, else &
    \int_compare:nTF { \l__peter_qtabular_cols_int = #1 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__peter_qtabular_body_tl { \\ }
      \int_zero:N \l__peter_qtabular_cols_int 
     }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__peter_qtabular_body_tl { & }
     }
   }
  % now fill the last row, if necessary; it isn't if the counter is 0
  \int_compare:nF { \l__peter_qtabular_cols_int == 0 }
   {% add as many & as necessary
    \prg_replicate:nn { #1 - \l__peter_qtabular_cols_int - 1 }
     { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__peter_qtabular_body_tl { & } }
    % add the final \\
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__peter_qtabular_body_tl { \\ }
   }
  % deliver the table
  \begin{tabular}{*{#1}{c}}
  \hline
  \tl_use:N \l__peter_qtabular_body_tl
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\qtabular{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}

\qtabular[3]{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}

\qtabular[5]{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot. What is the decicive difference that makes the & "behave" ?

Comment: @Peter The problem with your macro is that you start a loop in a cell and would like to end it in another which isn't possible, because cells make groups. So these macros don't start cells until the last moment, when the whole table body is delivered at once. I added a slightly modified version with comments.

Comment: ok, makes sense. Thanks. Impressive how fast this got solved! Great!

Answer (score 2):

A method without package.

Update:

- the macros are made `\long` to allow fringe cases such as

this

```
\qtabular[3]{A,
  \begin{minipage}{2cm}
    ABC\par DEF
  \end{minipage},
Z}
```

- a new macro `\qtabularnewline` is defined which allows to insert a `\\` at arbitrary locations as well as `\hline`'s or even `\noalign` material. Achieving the same functionality with an approach based on building up first the entire tabular material could be a bit complicated.

> [image: qtabular with qtabularnewline]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

% the update is a bit more clever and has less macros for more effects

\newcommand{\qtabular}[2][4]{% optional argument=nb of columns
  \begin{tabular}{*{#1}{c}}
    \qtabular@a {1}{#1}#2\qtabular@end,%
  \end{tabular}}

% The update makes the macros \long, to be compatible with \par tokens

\long\def\qtabular@a #1#2#3,{#3%
  \expandafter\qtabular@e\expandafter{\the\numexpr #1+1}{#2}}

% Use of \tabularnewline for extra-safety, but quasi unnecessary I guess.
\long\def\qtabular@e #1#2{\ifnum #2<#1
         \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\tabularnewline\qtabular@a {1}{#2}}%
    {&\qtabular@a {#1}{#2}}%
}

\def\qtabular@end\expandafter\qtabular@e\expandafter #1#2{}

\long\def\qtabularnewline #1\expandafter\qtabular@e\expandafter #2#3{%
    \ifnum #2=2 \else \expandafter\tabularnewline\fi
    \qtabular@a {1}{#3}#1,}
% minor remark: if the #1 from what followed \qtabularnewline in the
% input was braced, one level will be removed, but this
% has quasi nil importance, any how the new cell is a group, and #1 will
% occupy it entirely.

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\qtabular[3]{A,
  \begin{minipage}{2cm}
    ABC\par DEF
  \end{minipage},
Z}

\medskip

Using \verb|\fbox|es to check for spurious empty lines:
\medskip

\fbox{\qtabular[3]{\hline A,B,C\qtabularnewline\hline}}
=\fbox{\qtabular[3]{\hline A,B,C,\qtabularnewline\hline}}
=\fbox{\qtabular[3]{\hline A,B,C\\\hline}}
$\neq$\fbox{\qtabular[3]{\hline A,B,C,\\\hline}}

\fbox{\qtabular[3]{\hline A,B,C\qtabularnewline D}}
$\neq$
% a , after \qtabularnewline is like & after \\
\fbox{\qtabular[3]{\hline A,B,C\qtabularnewline, D}}

\fbox{\qtabular[12]{\hline\hline A,B,C\qtabularnewline\hline
                    D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,\qtabularnewline  % a comma
                    % before\qtabularnewline is authorized and non-significant
                    C,D,E,F,\qtabularnewline \hline 
                    G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J\qtabularnewline 
     \noalign{\hbox{DEMONSTRATING THE APPROACH FLEXIBILITY}}
                    A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J\\\hline\hline}}

\fbox{\qtabular[1]{A,B,C,\qtabularnewline}}% checking it is ok also at
                                % the end
\fbox{\qtabular[1]{\qtabularnewline\hline  A,\qtabularnewline\hline}}
and
\fbox{\qtabular[1]{\hline A\\\hline}}
and
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{c}
  \hline A\\\hline
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

---

First version:

> [image: qtabular]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\qtabular}[2][4]{% optional argument=nb of columns
  \begin{tabular}{*{#1}{c}}
    \qtabular@a 1{#1}#2,\qtabular@a,%
  \end{tabular}}

\def\qtabular@a #1#2#3,{%
    \qtabular@b #3\qtabular@c\qtabular@a\qtabular@d
    {#1}{#2}{#3}}

\def\qtabular@b #1\qtabular@a {}

\def\qtabular@c\qtabular@a\qtabular@d #1#2#3{}

\def\qtabular@d #1#2#3{#3%
  \expandafter\qtabular@e\expandafter{\the\numexpr #1+1}{#2}}

\def\qtabular@e #1#2{\ifnum #2<#1
         \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\\\qtabular@a {1}{#2}}%
    {&\qtabular@a {#1}{#2}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\hrule
\qtabular{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}
\hrule
\qtabular[3]{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}
\hrule
\qtabular[12]{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}
\hrule
\qtabular[5]{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}
\hrule
\qtabular[1]{A} and \qtabular[1]{A,B}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `\hrule` are just to check that no spurious empty line arises in a tabular.

Comment: Integrated this one and it works. Since I want to change a few things but am currently lost in the macro syntax here, can you recommend a page where this is well explained in detail and well. Thanks for writing it up!

Comment: @Peter this is a method based on the notion of macros with delimited parameters, thus its logic is quite peculiar to `TeX`; macros with parameters are explained in `TeX by Topic` ("texdoc topic"). The method, to avoid making definitions or using registers, uses `\numexpr` which is not covered in `TeX by Topic`, as it is a very recent thing in the tex world (late nineties `;-)` ). Thus, I am a bit at a loss for recommending a suitable page, the `e-TeX` manual ("texdoc etex") is very terse!